# How should we communication with the people who do not know the religion but are very prejudiced regarding the issue?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

In our surrounding there are  lot of people who express their ideas without having knowledge.They always speak against the religion .What should we do in our communication with them? Should we discuss with them or should we keep silent?

Comment: "Should we/I etc." questions are hardly on topic as they attract opinion-based answers. One of the best statements on this I've ever heard is that of imam Malik: One should tell the sunnah and not discuss (if people start doing so). As discussion -if it is not meant to clarify- is putting the people of knowledge in a bad light on might explain. As there are similar statements of him and other scholars on this. It might depend on many factors, but often you should say/present what Allah or his prophet said and stop at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to answer this question,first I would like to ask do you fill the Winds) of Allah*.If you wonder what is the Wind's of Allah then how can you seriously teach some one about the benefits of being a Muslim.Sura 61.2-3-4   I say this because to teach some one the benefits of being something,one should have the experience of what it is that they are trying to teach. The Winds is one of the Nine Signs of Mose's it is the Actions of Praying and it is what we as Muslims fight to save  an the winds is Glad Tiding to those who know.